# redirect std::cout to QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, iostream

Is it possible (and more importantly -how-) to redirect an output stream to a QTextBox. So that if I write `std::cout << "test"` anywhere in the application it gets redirected to a textbox I defined?

I tried the obvious (where ui.textEdit is a pointer to the text edit box):

```
std::cout.rdbuf(ui.textEdit);
std::cout << "test";
```

However this doesn't work. (obviously). - Nor does redirecting cout to qDebug work (or even direction a qDebug to a textfield).

I'm using qt4.8 btw...

EDIT:
So I tried the solution posted in the mailing list.. However now an access violation shows up.

```
class MainInterface : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
....
private: 
    QDebugStream qout
```

With the constructor:

```
MainInterface::MainInterface(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags),
    qout(std::cout, ui.textEdit)
{
```

And in a member function the following line is posted:  `std::cout << "Project Loaded" << std::endl;`

That line now causes an access violation from "qscoped_pointer". (Should I post this with more detail as seperate question?)

EDIT: well the "solution" was to only declare qout after the ui.textEdit was fully created.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote my own function for this problem , for a QTextEdit, just be aware that if you run it with heavy operations along the main Thread your GUI will freeze. So you have to instantiate a new QThread for example then the GUI respectively the QTextEdit will be updated accordingly:

Header File:

```
class myConsoleStream :  public std::basic_streambuf<char>
{

public:
    myConsoleStream(std::ostream &stream, QTextEdit* text_edit);

    virtual ~myConsoleStream();
    static void registerMyConsoleMessageHandler();

private:

    static void myConsoleMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &, const QString &msg);

protected:


    // Diese Funktion wird aufgerufen wenn std::endl im Stream erscheint
    virtual int_type overflow(int_type v)
        {
            if (v == '\n')
            {
                log_window->append("");
            }
            return v;
        }

    virtual std::streamsize xsputn(const char *p, std::streamsize n);

private:

    std::ostream &m_stream;
    std::streambuf *m_old_buf;
    QTextEdit* log_window;

};
#endif // Q_DEBUGSTREAM_H
```

.cpp File:

```
myConsoleStream::myConsoleStream(std::ostream &stream, QTextEdit* text_edit)
    :std::basic_streambuf<char>()
    ,m_stream(stream)


{
    this->log_window = text_edit;
    this->m_old_buf = stream.rdbuf();

    stream.rdbuf(this);

}

myConsoleStream::~myConsoleStream()
{
    this->m_stream.rdbuf(this->m_old_buf);
}

void myConsoleStream::registerMyConsoleMessageHandler()
{
    qInstallMessageHandler(myConsoleMessageHandler);
}


void myConsoleStream::myConsoleMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &, const QString &msg)
{

    QByteArray localMsg = msg.toLocal8Bit();
       switch (type) {
       case QtDebugMsg:
          // fprintf(stderr, "Debug: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
           break;
       case QtInfoMsg:
          // fprintf(stderr, "Info: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
           break;
       case QtWarningMsg:
          // fprintf(stderr, "Warning: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
           break;
       case QtCriticalMsg:
           //fprintf(stderr, "Critical: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
           break;
       case QtFatalMsg:
          // fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: %s (%s:%u, %s)\n", localMsg.constData(), context.file, context.line, context.function);
           break;
       default:
            std::cout << msg.toStdString().c_str();
           break;

       }
}
```

In your mainwindow you just have to instantiate your new Stream :

```
new myConsoleStream(std::cout, this->ui->Console);
  myConsoleStream::registerMyConsoleMessageHandler();
```

and you are good too go!
Hope this helps.

Comment: It misses xsputn function on your answer. A very similar working example can be found in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927087/redirecting-stdcout-from-dll-in-a-separate-thread-to-qtextedit

Answer (score 1):

You could reset `cout` to your own `ostream` implementation which would `emit` signals which you hook onto the [`append`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#append) slot. You sub-problems/exercises are therefore:

1. redirect `cout`
2. redirect `cout` to your own `ostream` implementation or one that you can extend
3. `emit` signals to `QTextBox`

---

*These sub-topics are available on SO, as far as I know*