# Qt forward stdout to QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, stdout

I have a `QPlainTextEdit` that can show the output of an external command.
I did this, using:

```
    connect(&m_process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [=]() { this->echo(m_process.readAllStandardOutput()); });
    connect(&m_process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, [=]()  { this->echo(m_process.readAllStandardError()); });
```

Now, I also want to show the output of my current process' stdout contents in this widget. Is there a way to "connect" that as well? Or how can I get a `QProcess` of the current process?

Comment: Reopen stdout to the writer end of a `pipe()` and have Qt watch the reader end?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308425/redirect-stdcout-to-a-qtextedit

Comment: Thank you. It was not what I needed, so I ended up passing a pointer to a printf-style function to all my code and thus bypass the printf function.

```
    // header.h
    typedef int __cdecl (*printf_ptr) (const char* format, ...);
    extern printf_ptr mi_printf;
    // implementation.cpp
    printf_ptr mi_printf = printf; // default
```